# How to make method in data access class for parameterized query?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp-classic, ado.net

I have created one method in data Access class to select data from database with parameter. I just want to use parameterized query.

Method Is :

```
public DataTable executeSelectQuery(String _query, SqlParameter[] sqlParameter)
            {
                SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand();
                DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
                dataTable = null;
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                try
                {
                    myCommand.Connection = openConnection();
                    myCommand.CommandText = _query;
                    myCommand.Parameters.AddRange(sqlParameter);
                    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    myAdapter.SelectCommand = myCommand;
                    myAdapter.Fill(ds);
                    dataTable = ds.Tables[0];
                }
                catch (SqlException e)
                {
                    return null;
                }
                finally
                {
                    myCommand.Connection = CloseConnection();
                }
                return dataTable;
            }
```

but I can't understand how to use this method to fetch data and how to pass parameter?

**My query may be `"select password from tblUsers where email=@email"` How to pass @email at business layer?**

**How to make method in data access class for getting Scalar value?**

```
public string getpasswrd(string unm)
    {
        con.Open();
        string cpaswrd;

        cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select password from tbl_login where username='" + unm + "'", con);
        cpaswrd = (String)cmd1.ExecuteScalar();
        con.Close();
        return cpaswrd;

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    SqlParameter param;

    cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select password from tbl_login where username=@username, con);

    param = new SqlParameter("@username", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
    param.Value = unm;
    cmd1.Parameters.Add(param);

    cpaswrd = cmd1.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use the same name in the sql parameter:
`new SqlParameter("email", "myemail@gmail.com")`